# Blender subdivision surface and bevel issues

Tags: mesh, edges

I am new to blender and having difficulty creating a mixture of hard and soft edges within a gun model I am making using the subdivision surface and bevel modifiers whilst keeping the vert count down.

I have added bevel weights to areas that I require to be hard, however if I don't continue this bevel all the way along the edge loop it does weird things with the topology, image of the bevels:

[image: Bevels]

Specifically, the front of the gun, if I don't continue the loop through the barrels it does the following:

[image: weird loop]

But If I do, the barrels become less circular but don't cause any of the cross looping seen.

[image: gun barrel issue]

Any suggestions as to how I should approach the bevelling as I want an easy enough topology to UV map next.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this gun model going to be a game asset?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to avoid poles and for the sake of sticking to quads, as a quick fix I'd suggest moving lower edge under the gun's barrel:

[image: Geometry Correction]